# How to create a latex file with html input value?

Tags: input, html

I have a latex file and a website. On the website I have an input field, in which you can write text. Then when you click a download-button on the website I want that it automatically creates a pdf (with latex) with the value of the input field.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain better your issue?

Comment: On the website I have an input field, in which you can write text. Then when you click a download-button I want that it automatically creates a pdf ( with latex) with the value of the input field.

Comment: Just to show it? if you can pass the input to a plain text file, said `foo.tex`, then you only need an already made  LateX template, said `main.tex` as  `\documentclass{article}\begin{document} Input: \input{foo} \end{document}`  and then run `pdflatex main.tex`.

Comment: https://texlive.net/run?do%20you%20mean%20like%20this?